# I cannot access Web Form controls on code-behind in Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, xamarin

I have created new ASP.NET (C#) Project on Xamarin IDE. My default page has some asp controls like labels, textboxes and buttons. When I try to access them from the code-behind I got this error :

```
error CS0103: The name xxxx does not exist in the current context.
```

This is the way i'm trying to access them :

```
usernameTXT.Text = "John";
```

This is my code-behind how it looks like :

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace advise
{

    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            usernameTXT.Text = "John";
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controls in the aspx page how it looks like :

```
<asp:TextBox id="usernameTXT" runat="server" CssClass="control"></asp:TextBox>
```

It is worth mentioning that nothing generated in the xxx.aspx.designer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace advise
{

    public partial class Default
    {

    }
}
```

Please help ! I tried to search about this issue with nothing helpful. It is strange thing since the code-behind is associated with the Web Form automatically as Xamarin did it for me.

Comment: Does "protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox usernameTXT;" exist in the auto-generated `XXXX.aspx.designer.cs` file? If not, "Rebuild All" and check again.

Comment: Actually nothing there generated in XXXX.aspx.designer.cs.

Comment: @RobertN I did the "Rebuild All" with no progress !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error CS0103: The name xxxx does not exist in the current context.

Does "protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox usernameTXT;" exist in the auto-generated XXXX.aspx.designer.cs file?

- If not, "Rebuild All" and check again.

If the `XXXX.aspx.designer.cs` (where XXXX is your page name, `Default` in your case) is not auto-updating to match your `asp:` definitions then you have a syntax error in your aspx/xml file.

Remove (or comment out) the definition that is causing the compile error and `Run` the project, the resulting web browser page will show you the parsing error and information about where the error is occurring in your `.aspx` file:

**Example:**

```
System.Web.Compilation.ParseException
Expecting </asp:TextBox> System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxControlBuilder

Description: Error parsing a resource required to service this request. Review your source file and modify it to fix this error.
Details: Expecting </asp:TextBox> System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBoxControlBuilder
Error origin: Parser
Error source file: /Users/administrator/Documents/Code/Xamarin/aspnet/aspnet/Default.aspx
Exception stack trace:
   at System.Web.Compilation.AspGenerator.Parse (System.IO.TextReader reader, System.String filename, Boolean doInitParser) in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/AspGenerator.cs:line 627
   at System.Web.Compilation.GenericBuildProvider`1[TParser].Parse () in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/GenericBuildProvider.cs:line 87
   at System.Web.Compilation.GenericBuildProvider`1[TParser].GenerateCode () in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/GenericBuildProvider.cs:line 102
   at System.Web.Compilation.GenericBuildProvider`1[TParser].GenerateCode (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder) in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/GenericBuildProvider.cs:line 121
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GenerateAssembly (System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder abuilder, System.Web.Compilation.BuildProviderGroup group, System.Web.VirtualPath vp, Boolean debug) in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/System.Web/System.Web.Compilation/BuildManager.cs:line 778
Error source context:
Error lines: 11, 11
9:      <asp:Button id="button1" runat="server" Text="Click me!" OnClick="button1Clicked" />
10:         <asp:TextBox id="usernameTXT" runat="server" CssClass="control">foobar</asp:TextBox>
11:         <asp:TextBox id="userneTXT" runat="server" CssClass="control">foobar</asp:TextBoxz>
12:     </form>
13: </body>
```